# Removing uploaded Image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I can upload an image and preview it using the following HTML code and function. But after I select the image and preview it, I don't want to actually upload the image, I want to reset the entire form.

How can I just remove the uploaded image?

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="newstatus" runat="server">
    <input type="file" id="imgInp" style="margin-top: 4px;" />
    <img id="status-img" src="#" alt="" width="150" height="150" />
    <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post" class="post-btn" id="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#status-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Please help me guys!

Comment: `$('#status-img').removeAttr('src')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subham, the JS code you are using is not upload your image to server. It just convert your selected image into BASE64 and show it on an image tag. If you want to remove that image from preview, just reset the **src** tag of image like:

```
$('#status-img').attr('src', '');
```

or

```
$('#status-img').removeAttr('src');
```

And to remove the selected image from input type image:

```
$('#imgInp').val('');
```

Comment: I not only want to remove the preview but also the image selected.. otherwise when I will click on submit it will still insert it into database